# Change timeout in run time - Elasticsearch RestHighLevelClient

Tags: java, elasticsearch, timeout, elasticsearch-high-level-restclient

Below is the Rest client initialization.

```
RestHighLevelClient client = new 
RestHighLevelClient(RestClient.builder(httpHost).setRequestConfigCallback(
    requestConfigBuilder -> requestConfigBuilder
        .setConnectTimeout(30000)
        .setSocketTimeout(90000));
```

Is there a way to change timeout values on the fly **without** reinitializing the rest client ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can very well define the timeout for each query level, please see [this](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/search/builder/SearchSourceBuilder.java#L474) timeout method which is available in JHLRC and can be added at query level.

So sample java code for your query looks like

```
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(USERS_INDEX_NAME);
        BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = new BoolQueryBuilder();
        boolQueryBuilder.minimumShouldMatch(1);
        MatchQueryBuilder emailMatchQueryBuilder = new MatchQueryBuilder("emailId", email);
        MatchQueryBuilder userIdMatchQueryBuilder = new MatchQueryBuilder("userId", userId);
        MatchQueryBuilder mobileMatchQueryBuilder = new MatchQueryBuilder("mobileNumber", mobile);
        boolQueryBuilder.should(emailMatchQueryBuilder);
        boolQueryBuilder.should(userIdMatchQueryBuilder);
        boolQueryBuilder.should(mobileMatchQueryBuilder);

        SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
        searchSourceBuilder.timeout(new TimeValue(1000)); // note this
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is for re-indexing. Couldn't see same kind of  a implementation is there with JHLRC for Re-indexing.

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera, through my answer I tried to explain that its a generic method which can be added at any query level, did you try adding it at your re-indexing code??

Comment: Yes. Below code is not working. Timeout defined below is not reflecting,. Always taking the timeout defined in client level.
        `ReindexRequest request = new ReindexRequest();
        request.setSourceIndices(indexName);
        request.setDestIndex(destinationIndex);
        request.setTimeout(new TimeValue(30000L));`

`ReindexRequestBuilder` doesn't have timeout option to set.

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera this is strange, how did you verify its not working and instead taking the timeout defined at client level?? i would suggest open a issue at https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues

Comment: I put 30s timeout to `RestHighLevelClient` and 30s timeout in `ReindexRequest`. When it throws the timeout exception I increased the timeout to 60s in `ReindexRequest` on the fly. Still it gives the timeout after 30s. Then I realized, it is taking the timeout from client but not from the re-indexing request.

Comment: Reported a bug https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/66913