# Set timeout in Elastic Java API Client

Tags: java, elasticsearch, java-8, elasticsearch-java-api, elasticsearch-high-level-restclient

I am trying to move from Elastic High level rest client to Elastic Java API Client (Low Level Rest Client). I am able to get the response, but i want to set the timeout for my elastic query.

But this timeout method is accepting a string value, which i am not able to pass the value here.

```
String searchText = "bike";

SearchResponse<Product> response = esClient.search(s -> s
    .index("products") 
 .timeout()
    .query(q -> q      
        .match(t -> t   
            .field("name")  
            .query(searchText)
        )
    ),
    Product.class      
);
```

This is the documentation for the method https://artifacts.elastic.co/javadoc/co/elastic/clients/elasticsearch-java/8.0.1/co/elastic/clients/elasticsearch/core/SearchRequest.Builder.html#timeout(java.lang.String)

Can someone help, how can I pass timeout value as String ??

Comment: from the docs, it says to use RestClientBuilder https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/master/_timeouts.html. There's another post similar to this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65503584/change-timeout-in-run-time-elasticsearch-resthighlevelclient

Comment: RestClientBuilder will help to set connect and socket timeout, I am trying to set a timeout for individual queries. Also, the link you shared was for High LevelRest client, whereas I am trying to use Low-Level Rest CLient, as the high level is getting deprecated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by passing a simple time value,

```
String searchText = "bike";

SearchResponse<Product> response = esClient.search(s -> s
    .index("products") 
 .timeout("450ms")
    .query(q -> q      
        .match(t -> t   
            .field("name")  
            .query(searchText)
        )
    ),
    Product.class      
);
```